# REST Streaming in Windows Phone App C#

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I've been using REST calls with my app to get and post data.  I want to implement REST streaming now though so that I can immediately get any changes to the data.

I have no clue how to implement REST streaming though.  How do I go about setting connection in my app.  Also, do you know have any tips or best practices when using REST streaming in an app.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never has a chance to try that but here is some clues that might help.

If you want to get a streamed content from your server, you can have a look at [HttpClient.GetAsync(Uri, HttpCompletionOption) | getAsync(Uri, HttpCompletionOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298645.aspx). The available options allow you to control how the response is handled. You can for example wait for the response headers and then once available read the response content stream from the [HttpResponseMessage.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage.content.aspx) property.

You can also have a look at the [IHttpFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.ihttpfilter.aspx) interface. It will allow you to "hook up" the HTTP stack and extract the response as it arrives.